# Define if numbers in list are less than one in parameter - Scala

Tags: scala, compare, logic

Write a function which at the input takes two parameters: a list of integers and a number.
The output returns a logical value.
The function returns "true" if all numbers in the list are smaller than the number given in the second parameter. Otherwise, the function returns "false".

My code:

```scala
def less [A](list:List[A], number:Int):Boolean =
  if (list == Nil) false
  else ((List.head < number) && less[A](list:List.tail, number:Int))


less(List(1, 2, 3, 4), 5)
less(List(6,1,2,3),6)
```

Error message in IntelliJ:

> On line 3: error: value head is not a member of object List
>
> else (List.head < number) && less[A](list:List.tail, number:Int) //2
>
> ^
>
> On line 3: error: type tail is not a member of object List

My question: What should I improve in this code to have it working?

Comment: For starters, change `List` to `list`

Comment: But why not just `list.forall(_ < number)`

Comment: Alright, it does work and is pretty simple, thanks. But still I would love to see where I was wrong in code above.

Comment: @Tomasz. Here's what I fixed to make it work: 0) Added curlies after `=` and at end of code, 1) Changed `List.head` to `list.head` and `list:List.tail` to `list.tail`, Removed all mentions of `[A]` in favor of  `list:List[Int]` for first parameter. What would you expect to happen if you pass in some other non-numeric type?.

Comment: @Tomasz Code: `def less (list:List[Int], number:Int):Boolean = {  if (list == Nil) false  else ((list.head < number) && less(list.tail, number:Int)) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems an awful lot like home work...

Scala has a `forall` function that can test a predicate against all values in the collection and returns a `Boolean`.

`def less(xs: List[Int], number: Int) = xs.forall(x => ???)`

Comment: I wonder if is it possible to do with recursion and logic just like I did? I'll check out this `forall` function.

Comment: @Tomasz It certainly is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
def less (list:List[Int], number:Int):Boolean =
  if (list == Nil) true
  else ((list.head < number) && less(list.tail, number))


less(List(1, 2, 3, 4), 5)//true
less(List(6,1,2,3),6)//false
```

But you should just use forall like @Brian said